# Autohotkey setting up "..println" read something

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make shortcut using autohotkey where typing "println" produces "System.out.println();" but typing ".println" produces ".println();".
The purpose of this is to help me with something I commonly type when I'm writing code for my java course. I want use the regular keyboard dot to be not the numpad dot for this shortcut but I do not care about which dot is used in the output.

I have tried the following:

```
;for Java println
::println::
SendInput System.out.println();{Left}{Left}
return


;block change if '.println'
::.println::
SendInput {NumpadDot}println();{Left}{Left}
return
```

However, this only does the first shortcut and not the second.
Can you help me get this script to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `::.println::` before `::println::` and your idea will work.

```
::. println::  ; you might wan't to add this in case you add a space after a ,
SendInput {NumpadDot}println();{Left}{Left}
return

::.println::
SendInput {NumpadDot}println();{Left}{Left}
return


::println::
SendInput System.out.println();{Left}{Left}
return
```

Comment: Thanks for tackling this, Armin. I tried your script but it still seems to fail. Used by themselves they work.... ".println" does exactly what I want. But then when you try "output.println" it converts the text to "output.System.out.println();" Any idea what's going on and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Use an `?` in your hotstrings. `:?:.println::`. Didn't you read this http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm ?

Comment: Oh, I haven't used autohotkey in a while and that feature just slipped my mind. My apologize. It's working now, thanks!